# Celebrating 265 Famous Question badges

Tags: discussion, questions, users, badges

More than 10% of our [open questions (1,744)](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano) are [famous questions (265)](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question)! That means each of these questions have been seen over *10,000* times each! Some questions have been viewed hundreds of thousands of times, such as [How to sleep with a stuffy / blocked nose?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/6229/15) which has exceeded half a million.

From us moderators to all, thank you!

*Answers on this question may include other interesting statistics that you think make Lifehacks especially useful!*

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty impressed by the fact that the number of **unique users who have posted an answer** is ***more than double*** the number of **unique users who have asked a question** ([Check it out!](http://data.stackexchange.com/lifehacks/query/859877/question-askers-vs-question-answerers))

It's very promising to see that Lifehacks SE is filled with so many people wanting *give* answers, not just *get* answers!

(At the time of posting this, there were 1097 Askers and 2362 Answerers, with an intersection of 372 users)

Comment: That's great, thank you!